# Accessing nested hashmap in freemarker

Tags: hash, freemarker

I have the following structure where I need to access the list from the inner hashmap

```
Map(key, (Map (key, list ))
```

What is the easiest way to access the list in frermarker

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys in the Map-s are `Strings`: `foo[key1][key2][index]`